# Combine elements of matrix in R

Tags: r

This is my sample data

```
> matrix
              a     b     c     d 
W_1_N        NA    NA    NA    NA  
W_1_E         2     2     2     4   
W_1_C         4     2     2     4  
W_1_D        NA    NA    NA    NA
```

I have to combine elements from matrix to get pairs of column names of them, where one of element is 4 and another is 2 in the same row.

In a result it should look like this

```
W_1_E  d  a
W_1_E  d  b
W_1_E  d  c
W_1_C  a  b
W_1_C  a  c
W_1_C  d  b
W_1_C  d  c
```

I want only pairs where one element is 4 and other is 2 in the same row. `W_1_N` and `W_1_D` have only `NA` so was ommited. `W_1_E` appears in 3 rows because there are 3 pairs of (4,2) in row in sample data.`W_1_C` has 4 pairs. I tried with loops but I don't know what should be in `data.frame`.

```
for (i in row(matrix)){
  for (j in col(matrixz)){
    if (matrix[i,j]==4){
      ram=data.frame(

      )
    }

  }
}
```

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
library(tidyverse)

lst <- data.frame(m) %>%
  rownames_to_column("rn") %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  gather(key, value, -rn) %>%
  group_by(rn, value) %>%
  summarise(l = list(unique(key))) %>%
  split(.$rn)

do.call("rbind", lapply(lst, function(x) expand.grid(x$l[[1]], x$l[[2]])))
```

Which gives:

```
#        Var1 Var2
#W_1_C.1    b    a
#W_1_C.2    c    a
#W_1_C.3    b    d
#W_1_C.4    c    d
#W_1_E.1    a    d
#W_1_E.2    b    d
#W_1_E.3    c    d
```

---

**Data**

```
m <- structure(c(NA, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 
4L, 4L, NA), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("W_1_N", "W_1_E", 
"W_1_C", "W_1_D"), c("a", "b", "c", "d")))
```